strdup giving weird warning and Segmentation fault
I was working on other project and found, for me, strange behaviour from strdup.
Lets say we have 3 simple files:
foo.h:
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

void example(char *a);

#endif //FOO_H 

foo.c:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "foo.h"

void example(char *a) {
    if (a == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "a is NULL");
        exit(1);
    }
    char *temp = strdup(a);
    printf("%s", temp);
}

bar.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "foo.h"

int main() {
    char *a = "Hello World\n";
    example(a);
    return 0;
}

When I compile these, I get warning and when I run these, I get seg fault:
foo.c:10:18: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strdup’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
foo.c:10:18: warning: initialization of ‘char *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

The solution is to not compile with c11 or put your own strdup declaration in the .h file.
So the question is, why is this happening.

Isn't the actual solution to #include <string.h>?

look at SYNOPSIS in strdup(3)

The warning isn't weird, strdup hasn't been declared because you didn't include <sting.h>. Actually warning: implicit declaration of function ... is more of an error than a warning and it should almost always be considered as an error nowadays. Same for ...makes pointer from integer without a cast... diagnostics.

@yano — the problem was in the Markdown — the #ifndef FOO_H code was on the same line as the triple backtick.  I simply added the necessary newline.  But the OP should have checked that what they saw in the preview, or after the question was posted, didn't match what was intended and should have fixed the problem themselves.


The solution is to not compile with c11 or put your own strdup declaration in the .h file.

No, the solution is to include string.h for strdup().
About the error messages, see: Implicit function declarations in C and Are prototypes required for all functions in C89, C90 or C99?.
Also note that strdup() allocates memory dynamically with malloc() which needs to be deallocated. You're missing a call to free() in your code.
Additionally, it returns a null pointer if it failed to allocate memory, in which case temp would hold a null pointer, and the subsequent call to printf() would invoke undefined behavior.

Still no change when compiled with gcc -std=c11

Where have you read that strdup() is part of C11, or even C18? It has been standardized in C2X. If you're not compiling with std=c2x, you'd have to define _POSIX_C_SOURCE and/or _XOPEN_SOURCE tk appropriate values (see the man page) before the inclusion of the header files. Or enable GNU C extensions (std=gnu..) which I won't recommend.
